# FFMPEG API Mp4 H264 Encoding/Muxing - unspecified pixel format

Tags: c++, video, encoding, ffmpeg, mp4

I'm working on a c++ project using ffmpeg. I have to generate an mp4 file with h264 encoding.

My problem is that the file generate but when reading the file with VLC I've got no image, and analyzing it with ffprobe give me (log below) the error:

> unspecified pixel format

```
ffprobe version N-93020-g3224d6691c Copyright (c) 2007-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8.2.1 (GCC) 20181201
  configuration: --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt
  libavutil      56. 26.100 / 56. 26.100
  libavcodec     58. 44.100 / 58. 44.100
  libavformat    58. 26.100 / 58. 26.100
  libavdevice    58.  6.101 / 58.  6.101
  libavfilter     7. 48.100 /  7. 48.100
  libswscale      5.  4.100 /  5.  4.100
  libswresample   3.  4.100 /  3.  4.100
  libpostproc    55.  4.100 / 55.  4.100
[h264 @ 02a46240] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 02a46240] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 02a46240] no frame!
...
[h264 @ 02a46240] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 02a46240] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 02a46240] no frame!
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 02a35380] decoding for stream 0 failed
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 02a35380] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), none, 352x288, 320 kb/s): unspecified pixel format
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'C:\Users\Fabrice\Desktop\video\Test.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.26.100
  Duration: 00:00:09.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 323 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), none, 352x288, 320 kb/s, 25.11 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 25600 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
```

Here is the code I use to genererate my mp4 File, it's based on sample from ffmpeg (see: [FFMPEG Muxing sample](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.1/doc_2examples_2muxing_8c-example.html)). I have tried to adapt it without using deprecated function. It works using webm/vp8 encoding, but not mp4/h264.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
extern "C"
{
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libswscale/swscale.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <libavutil/error.h> 
#include <libavutil/opt.h>
#include <libavutil/imgutils.h>
}

#pragma comment(lib, "avcodec.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "swscale.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "avformat.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "avutil.lib")

/* 10 seconds stream duration */
#define STREAM_DURATION   10.0
#define STREAM_FRAME_RATE 25 /* 25 images/s */
#define STREAM_NB_FRAMES  ((int)(STREAM_DURATION * STREAM_FRAME_RATE))
#define STREAM_PIX_FMT    AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P /* default pix_fmt */

//#pragma warning(disable : 4996) // TODO: remove

static int sws_flags = SWS_BICUBIC;

/* Add an output stream. */
static AVStream *add_stream(AVFormatContext *formatContext, AVCodec **codec, enum AVCodecID codecId, AVCodecContext **codecCtx)
{
    AVStream *stream;

    // Get the encoder codec
    *codec = avcodec_find_encoder(codecId);
    if (!(*codec)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not find encoder for '%s'\n",
            avcodec_get_name(codecId));
        exit(1);
    }

    // Get the stream for codec
    stream = avformat_new_stream(formatContext, *codec);
    if (!stream) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate stream\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    stream->id = formatContext->nb_streams - 1;

    (*codecCtx) = avcodec_alloc_context3(*codec);

    switch ((*codec)->type) {
    case AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO:
        stream->codecpar->codec_id = codecId;
        stream->codecpar->codec_type = AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO;
        stream->codecpar->bit_rate = 400000;
        stream->codecpar->width = 352;
        stream->codecpar->height = 288;
        stream->codecpar->format = STREAM_PIX_FMT;
        stream->time_base = { 1, STREAM_FRAME_RATE };

        avcodec_parameters_to_context((*codecCtx), stream->codecpar);
        (*codecCtx)->gop_size = 12; /* emit one intra frame every twelve frames at most */
        (*codecCtx)->max_b_frames = 2;
        (*codecCtx)->time_base = { 1, STREAM_FRAME_RATE };
        if ((*codecCtx)->codec_id == AV_CODEC_ID_MPEG1VIDEO) {
            /* Needed to avoid using macroblocks in which some coeffs overflow.
             * This does not happen with normal video, it just happens here as
             * the motion of the chroma plane does not match the luma plane. */
            (*codecCtx)->mb_decision = 2;
        }
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
    
    //if (stream->codecpar->codec_id == AV_CODEC_ID_H264) {
    //  av_opt_set(codecCtx, "preset", "ultrafast", 0);
    //}
    //(*codecCtx)->flags |= AV_CODEC_FLAG_LOW_DELAY;

    /* Some formats want stream headers to be separate. */
    if (formatContext->oformat->flags & AVFMT_GLOBALHEADER)
        (*codecCtx)->flags |= AV_CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;


    int ret = avcodec_parameters_from_context(stream->codecpar, (*codecCtx));
    if (ret < 0) {
        char error[255];
        av_strerror(ret, error, 255);
        fprintf(stderr, "avcodec_parameters_from_context returned (%d) - %s", ret, error);
        return false;
    }

    return stream;
}

/**************************************************************/
/* video output */

static AVFrame *frame_video;
static int frame_count;

static void open_video(AVCodec *codec, AVStream *stream, AVCodecContext *codecCtx)
{
    int ret;

    /* open the codec */
    ret = avcodec_open2(codecCtx, codec, NULL);
    if (ret < 0) {
        char error[255];
        av_strerror(ret, error, 255);
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open video codec: %s\n", error);
        exit(1);
    }

    /* allocate and init a re-usable frame */
    frame_video = av_frame_alloc();
    if (!frame_video) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate video frame\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    frame_video->format = codecCtx->pix_fmt;
    frame_video->width = codecCtx->width;
    frame_video->height = codecCtx->height;

    ret = av_frame_get_buffer(frame_video, 32);
    if (ret < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate the video frame data\n");
        exit(1);
    }
}

/* Prepare a dummy image. */
static void fill_yuv_image(AVFrame *pict, int frame_index, int width, int height)
{
    int x, y, i;

    i = frame_index;

    /* Y */
    for (y = 0; y < height; y++)
        for (x = 0; x < width; x++)
            pict->data[0][y * pict->linesize[0] + x] = x + y + i * 3;

    /* Cb and Cr */
    for (y = 0; y < height / 2; y++) {
        for (x = 0; x < width / 2; x++) {
            pict->data[1][y * pict->linesize[1] + x] = 128 + y + i * 2;
            pict->data[2][y * pict->linesize[2] + x] = 64 + x + i * 5;
        }
    }
}

int timestamp = 0;
static void write_video_frame(AVFormatContext *formatContext, AVStream *stream, AVCodecContext *codecCtx)
{
    int ret;
    static struct SwsContext *sws_ctx;

    if (frame_count >= STREAM_NB_FRAMES) {
        /* No more frames to compress. The codec has a latency of a few
         * frames if using B-frames, so we get the last frames by
         * passing the same picture again. */
    }
    else {
        if (codecCtx->pix_fmt != AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P) {
            /* as we only generate a YUV420P picture, we must convert it
             * to the codec pixel format if needed */
            if (!sws_ctx) {
                sws_ctx = sws_getContext(codecCtx->width, codecCtx->height, AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P,
                    codecCtx->width, codecCtx->height, codecCtx->pix_fmt,
                    sws_flags, NULL, NULL, NULL);
                if (!sws_ctx) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Could not initialize the conversion context\n");
                    exit(1);
                }
            }
            fill_yuv_image(frame_video, frame_count, codecCtx->width, codecCtx->height);
            sws_scale(sws_ctx, (const uint8_t * const *)frame_video->data, frame_video->linesize,
                0, codecCtx->height, frame_video->data, frame_video->linesize);
        }
        else {
            fill_yuv_image(frame_video, frame_count, codecCtx->width, codecCtx->height);
        }
    }

    frame_video->format = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;
    frame_video->width = codecCtx->width;
    frame_video->height = codecCtx->height;

    if (formatContext->oformat->flags & 0x0020) {
        /* Raw video case - directly store the picture in the packet */
        AVPacket pkt;
        av_init_packet(&pkt);

        pkt.flags |= AV_PKT_FLAG_KEY;
        pkt.stream_index = stream->index;
        pkt.data = frame_video->data[0];
        pkt.size = sizeof(AVPicture);

        ret = av_interleaved_write_frame(formatContext, &pkt);
    }
    else {
        AVPacket pkt = { 0 };
        av_init_packet(&pkt);

        /* encode the image */
        fprintf(stderr, "\nFrame type : %c\n", av_get_picture_type_char(frame_video->pict_type));
        fprintf(stderr, "Frame pts: %lld, \n", frame_video->pts);
        fprintf(stderr, "Codec timebase: %d/%d\n", codecCtx->time_base.num, codecCtx->time_base.den);
        fprintf(stderr, "Stream timebase: %d/%d\n", stream->time_base.num, stream->time_base.den);
        fprintf(stderr, "Resacale: %lld, \n\n", av_rescale_q(1, codecCtx->time_base, stream->time_base));
        ret = avcodec_send_frame(codecCtx, frame_video);
        if (ret < 0) {
            char error[255];
            av_strerror(ret, error, 255);
            fprintf(stderr, "Error encoding video frame: %s\n", error);
            exit(1);
        }
        /* If size is zero, it means the image was buffered. */
        ret = avcodec_receive_packet(codecCtx, &pkt);
        if (!ret && pkt.size) {
            pkt.stream_index = stream->index;
            fprintf(stderr, "Packet flags : %d\n", pkt.flags);
            fprintf(stderr, "Packet pts: %lld\n", pkt.pts);
            fprintf(stderr, "Packet dts: %lld\n", pkt.dts);
            fprintf(stderr, "Packet duration: %lld\n", pkt.duration);
            fprintf(stderr, "Packet pos: %lld\n\n", pkt.pos);
            
            /* Write the compressed frame to the media file. */
            ret = av_interleaved_write_frame(formatContext, &pkt);
        }
        else {
            ret = 0;
        }
    }
    if (ret != 0) {
        char error[255];
        av_strerror(ret, error, 255);
        fprintf(stderr, "Error while writing video frame: %s\n", error);
        exit(1);
    }
    frame_count++;
}

static void close_video(AVFormatContext *oc, AVStream *st)
{
    av_free(frame_video->data[0]);
    av_free(frame_video);
}

/**************************************************************/
/* media file output */

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // The outputed media
    char filename[100];
    const char *mediaFormat = "mp4"; AVCodecID mediaVideoCodec = AV_CODEC_ID_H264;
    //const char *mediaFormat="webm"; AVCodecID mediaVideoCodec = AV_CODEC_ID_VP8;
    AVOutputFormat *formatOut;
    AVFormatContext *formatCtx;

    // The video stream
    AVStream *stream_video;
    AVCodec *codec_video = nullptr;
    AVCodecContext *codecCtx_video = nullptr;
    double time_video = 0;

    // Return code
    int ret;

    strcpy_s(filename, "C:\\Test.");
    strcat_s(filename, mediaFormat);

    // allocate the output media context
    avformat_alloc_output_context2(&formatCtx, NULL, NULL, filename);
    if (!formatCtx) {
        return 1;
    }
    formatOut = formatCtx->oformat;

    // Add the video stream using H264 codec
    stream_video = NULL;
    stream_video = add_stream(formatCtx, &codec_video, mediaVideoCodec, &codecCtx_video);

    // Open video codec and allocate the necessary encode buffers
    if (stream_video)
        open_video(codec_video, stream_video, codecCtx_video);

    av_dump_format(formatCtx, 0, filename, 1);

    // Open the output media file, if needed
    if (!(formatOut->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE)) {
        ret = avio_open(&formatCtx->pb, filename, AVIO_FLAG_WRITE);
        if (ret < 0) {
            char error[255];
            av_strerror(ret, error, 255);
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not open '%s': %s\n", filename, error);
            return 1;
        }
    }

    // Write media header
    ret = avformat_write_header(formatCtx, NULL);
    if (ret < 0) {
        char error[255];
        av_strerror(ret, error, 255);
        fprintf(stderr, "Error occurred when opening output file: %s\n", error);
        return 1;
    }

    if (frame_video)
        frame_video->pts = 0;
    for (;;) {
        // Compute video time from last added video frame
        time_video = ((double)frame_video->pts) * av_q2d(stream_video->time_base);

        // Stop media if enough time
        if (!stream_video || time_video >= STREAM_DURATION)
            break;

        // Add a video frame
        write_video_frame(formatCtx, stream_video, codecCtx_video);

        // Increase frame pts according to time base
        frame_video->pts += av_rescale_q(1, codecCtx_video->time_base, stream_video->time_base);
    }

    // Write media trailer
    av_write_trailer(formatCtx);

    /* Close each codec. */
    if (stream_video)
        close_video(formatCtx, stream_video);

    if (!(formatOut->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE))
        /* Close the output file. */
        avio_close(formatCtx->pb);

    /* free the stream */
    avformat_free_context(formatCtx);

    return 0;
}
```

What am I missing? Which part give me this error?

Comment: I don't use FFmpeg with C++ but.. The first problem I see is: `Non-existing PPS 0 referenced` and if you have no **Picture Parameter Settings** then you can't decode a picture. **(1)** Make sure your first frame is encoded as a **keyframe** (is there a setting to mark frame data as key?) **(2)** Since MP4 can be akward, I recommend outputting just raw H264, and see if that works, also then try a container format like FLV or AVI. This will eliminate whether the problem is that your MP4 has missing `MOOV` atom which contains the PPS. The other containers don't work like MP4 and might be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got to comment these lines to make it work.

```
if (formatContext->oformat->flags & AVFMT_GLOBALHEADER)
    (*codecCtx)->flags |= AV_CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;
```

here is the full code with some correction :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
extern "C"
{
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libswscale/swscale.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <libavutil/error.h> 
#include <libavutil/opt.h>
#include <libavutil/imgutils.h>
}

#pragma comment(lib, "avcodec.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "swscale.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "avformat.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "avutil.lib")

/* 10 seconds stream duration */
#define STREAM_DURATION   100.0
#define STREAM_FRAME_RATE 25 /* 25 images/s */
#define STREAM_NB_FRAMES  ((int)(STREAM_DURATION * STREAM_FRAME_RATE))
#define STREAM_PIX_FMT    AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P /* default pix_fmt */

//#pragma warning(disable : 4996) // TODO: remove

static int sws_flags = SWS_BICUBIC;

static int __WritePacket(void* opaque, uint8_t* buf, int buf_size)
{
    FILE *f = (FILE *)opaque;
    
    fprintf(stderr, "writen : %d\n", fwrite(buf, sizeof(uint8_t), buf_size, f));
    fflush(f);

    return buf_size;
}

/* Add an output stream. */
static AVStream *add_stream(AVFormatContext *formatContext, AVCodec **codec, enum AVCodecID codecId, AVCodecContext **codecCtx)
{
    AVStream *stream;

    // Get the encoder codec
    *codec = avcodec_find_encoder(codecId);
    if (!(*codec)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not find encoder for '%s'\n",
            avcodec_get_name(codecId));
        exit(1);
    }

    // Get the stream for codec
    stream = avformat_new_stream(formatContext, *codec);
    if (!stream) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate stream\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    stream->id = formatContext->nb_streams - 1;

    (*codecCtx) = avcodec_alloc_context3(*codec);

    switch ((*codec)->type) {
    case AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO:
        stream->codecpar->codec_id = codecId;
        stream->codecpar->codec_type = AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO;
        stream->codecpar->bit_rate = 400000;
        stream->codecpar->width = 352;
        stream->codecpar->height = 288;
        stream->codecpar->format = STREAM_PIX_FMT;
        stream->codecpar->codec_tag = 0x31637661;
        stream->codecpar->video_delay = 0;
        stream->time_base = { 1, STREAM_FRAME_RATE };

        avcodec_parameters_to_context((*codecCtx), stream->codecpar);
        (*codecCtx)->gop_size = 12; /* emit one intra frame every twelve frames at most */
        (*codecCtx)->max_b_frames = 2;
        (*codecCtx)->time_base = { 1, STREAM_FRAME_RATE };
        (*codecCtx)->framerate = { STREAM_FRAME_RATE, 1 };
        (*codecCtx)->pix_fmt = STREAM_PIX_FMT;
        if ((*codecCtx)->codec_id == AV_CODEC_ID_MPEG1VIDEO) {
            /* Needed to avoid using macroblocks in which some coeffs overflow.
             * This does not happen with normal video, it just happens here as
             * the motion of the chroma plane does not match the luma plane. */
            (*codecCtx)->mb_decision = 2;
        }
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    /* Some formats want stream headers to be separate. */
    // Setting this option make the video stream not readable.
//  if (formatContext->oformat->flags & AVFMT_GLOBALHEADER)
//      (*codecCtx)->flags |= AV_CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;


    int ret = avcodec_parameters_from_context(stream->codecpar, (*codecCtx));
    if (ret < 0) {
        char error[255];
        av_strerror(ret, error, 255);
        fprintf(stderr, "avcodec_parameters_from_context returned (%d) - %s", ret, error);
        return false;
    }

    return stream;
}

/**************************************************************/
/* video output */

static AVFrame *frame_video;
static int frame_count;

static void open_video(AVCodec *codec, AVStream *stream, AVCodecContext *codecCtx)
{
    int ret;

    /* open the codec */
    ret = avcodec_open2(codecCtx, codec, NULL);
    if (ret < 0) {
        char error[255];
        av_strerror(ret, error, 255);
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open video codec: %s\n", error);
        exit(1);
    }

    /* allocate and init a re-usable frame */
    frame_video = av_frame_alloc();
    if (!frame_video) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate video frame\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    frame_video->format = codecCtx->pix_fmt;
    frame_video->width = codecCtx->width;
    frame_video->height = codecCtx->height;

    ret = av_frame_get_buffer(frame_video, 32);
    if (ret < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate the video frame data\n");
        exit(1);
    }
}

/* Prepare a dummy image. */
static void fill_yuv_image(AVFrame *pict, int frame_index, int width, int height)
{
    int x, y, i;

    i = frame_index;

    /* Y */
    for (y = 0; y < height; y++)
        for (x = 0; x < width; x++)
            pict->data[0][y * pict->linesize[0] + x] = x + y + i * 3;

    /* Cb and Cr */
    for (y = 0; y < height / 2; y++) {
        for (x = 0; x < width / 2; x++) {
            pict->data[1][y * pict->linesize[1] + x] = 128 + y + i * 2;
            pict->data[2][y * pict->linesize[2] + x] = 64 + x + i * 5;
        }
    }
}

int timestamp = 0;
static void write_video_frame(AVFormatContext *formatContext, AVStream *stream, AVCodecContext *codecCtx)
{
    int ret;
    static struct SwsContext *sws_ctx;

    if (frame_count >= STREAM_NB_FRAMES) {
        /* No more frames to compress. The codec has a latency of a few
         * frames if using B-frames, so we get the last frames by
         * passing the same picture again. */
    }
    else {
        if (codecCtx->pix_fmt != STREAM_PIX_FMT) {
            /* as we only generate a YUV420P picture, we must convert it
             * to the codec pixel format if needed */
            if (!sws_ctx) {
                sws_ctx = sws_getContext(codecCtx->width, codecCtx->height, STREAM_PIX_FMT,
                    codecCtx->width, codecCtx->height, codecCtx->pix_fmt,
                    sws_flags, NULL, NULL, NULL);
                if (!sws_ctx) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Could not initialize the conversion context\n");
                    exit(1);
                }
            }
            fill_yuv_image(frame_video, frame_count, codecCtx->width, codecCtx->height);
            sws_scale(sws_ctx, (const uint8_t * const *)frame_video->data, frame_video->linesize,
                0, codecCtx->height, frame_video->data, frame_video->linesize);
        }
        else {
            fill_yuv_image(frame_video, frame_count, codecCtx->width, codecCtx->height);
        }
    }

    frame_video->format = STREAM_PIX_FMT;
    frame_video->width = codecCtx->width;
    frame_video->height = codecCtx->height;

    if (formatContext->oformat->flags & 0x0020) {
        /* Raw video case - directly store the picture in the packet */
        AVPacket pkt;
        av_init_packet(&pkt);

        pkt.flags |= AV_PKT_FLAG_KEY;
        pkt.stream_index = stream->index;
        pkt.data = frame_video->data[0];
        pkt.size = sizeof(AVPicture);

        ret = av_interleaved_write_frame(formatContext, &pkt);
    }
    else {
        AVPacket packet = { 0 };
        av_init_packet(&packet);

        /* encode the image */
        fprintf(stderr, "\nFrame type : %c\n", av_get_picture_type_char(frame_video->pict_type));
        fprintf(stderr, "Frame pts: %lld, \n", frame_video->pts);
        fprintf(stderr, "Codec timebase: %d/%d\n", codecCtx->time_base.num, codecCtx->time_base.den);
        fprintf(stderr, "Stream timebase: %d/%d\n", stream->time_base.num, stream->time_base.den);
        fprintf(stderr, "Resacale: %lld, \n\n", av_rescale_q(1, codecCtx->time_base, stream->time_base));
        ret = avcodec_send_frame(codecCtx, frame_video);
        if (ret < 0) {
            char error[255];
            av_strerror(ret, error, 255);
            fprintf(stderr, "Error encoding video frame: %s\n", error);
            exit(1);
        }
        /* If size is zero, it means the image was buffered. */
        ret = avcodec_receive_packet(codecCtx, &packet);
        if (!ret && packet.size) {
            packet.stream_index = stream->index;
            fprintf(stderr, "Packet flags : %d\n", packet.flags);
            fprintf(stderr, "Packet pts: %lld\n", packet.pts);
            fprintf(stderr, "Packet dts: %lld\n", packet.dts);
            fprintf(stderr, "Packet duration: %lld\n", packet.duration);
            fprintf(stderr, "Packet pos: %lld\n\n", packet.pos);

            FILE *f = nullptr;
            fopen_s(&f, "C:\\Users\\Fabrice\\Desktop\\video\\Test.h264", "wb");
            fwrite(packet.data, sizeof(uint8_t), packet.size, f);
            fclose(f);

            /* Write the compressed frame to the media file. */
            ret = av_interleaved_write_frame(formatContext, &packet);
        }
        else {
            ret = 0;
        }
    }
    if (ret != 0) {
        char error[255];
        av_strerror(ret, error, 255);
        fprintf(stderr, "Error while writing video frame: %s\n", error);
        exit(1);
    }
    frame_count++;
}

static void close_video(AVFormatContext *oc, AVStream *st)
{
    av_free(frame_video->data[0]);
    av_free(frame_video);
}

/**************************************************************/
/* media file output */

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    // The outputed media
    char filename[100];
    const char *mediaFormat = "mp4"; AVCodecID mediaVideoCodec = AV_CODEC_ID_H264;
    //const char *mediaFormat="webm"; AVCodecID mediaVideoCodec = AV_CODEC_ID_VP8;
    AVOutputFormat *formatOut;
    AVFormatContext *formatCtx;

    // The video stream
    AVStream *stream_video;
    AVCodec *codec_video = nullptr;
    AVCodecContext *codecCtx_video = nullptr;
    double time_video = 0;

    // Return code
    int ret;

    strcpy_s(filename, "C:\\Users\\Fabrice\\Desktop\\video\\Test.");
    strcat_s(filename, mediaFormat);

    remove("C:\\Users\\Fabrice\\Desktop\\video\\Test.h264");
    remove(filename);

    // allocate the output media context
    avformat_alloc_output_context2(&formatCtx, NULL, NULL, filename);
    if (!formatCtx) {
        return 1;
    }
    formatOut = formatCtx->oformat;

    // Add the video stream using H264 codec
    stream_video = NULL;
    stream_video = add_stream(formatCtx, &codec_video, mediaVideoCodec, &codecCtx_video);

    // Open video codec and allocate the necessary encode buffers
    if (stream_video)
        open_video(codec_video, stream_video, codecCtx_video);

    av_dump_format(formatCtx, 0, filename, 1);

    /*// Open the output media file, if needed
    if (!(formatOut->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE)) {
        ret = avio_open(&formatCtx->pb, filename, AVIO_FLAG_WRITE);
        if (ret < 0) {
            char error[255];
            av_strerror(ret, error, 255);
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not open '%s': %s\n", filename, error);
            return 1;
        }
    }*/

    uint8_t *ioBuffer = (uint8_t*)av_malloc(4096);
    if (!ioBuffer) {
        return 1;
    }
    
    FILE *f = nullptr;
    fopen_s(&f, filename, "wb");

    AVIOContext *ioCtx = avio_alloc_context(ioBuffer, 4096, 1, f, NULL, __WritePacket, NULL);
    if (!ioCtx) {
        return 1;
    }
    formatCtx->pb = ioCtx;
    formatCtx->flush_packets = 1;

    fprintf(stderr, "Stream timebase: %d/%d\n", stream_video->time_base.num, stream_video->time_base.den);

    // Fragmented mp4
    AVDictionary* opts = NULL;
    av_dict_set(&opts, "movflags", "frag_keyframe+empty_moov", 0);

    // Write media header
    ret = avformat_write_header(formatCtx, &opts);
    if (ret < 0) {
        char error[255];
        av_strerror(ret, error, 255);
        fprintf(stderr, "Error occurred when opening output file: %s\n", error);
        return 1;
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "Stream timebase: %d/%d\n", stream_video->time_base.num, stream_video->time_base.den);

    if (frame_video)
        frame_video->pts = 0;
    for (;;) {
        // Compute video time from last added video frame
        time_video = ((double)frame_video->pts) * av_q2d(stream_video->time_base);

        // Stop media if enough time
        if (!stream_video || time_video >= STREAM_DURATION)
            break;

        // Add a video frame
        write_video_frame(formatCtx, stream_video, codecCtx_video);

        // Increase frame pts according to time base
        frame_video->pts += av_rescale_q(1, codecCtx_video->time_base, stream_video->time_base);
    }

    // Write media trailer
    av_write_trailer(formatCtx);

    /* Close each codec. */
    if (stream_video)
        close_video(formatCtx, stream_video);

    /* free the stream */
    avformat_free_context(formatCtx);

    return 0;
}
```